# How do I obtain the location of the previous Makefile/second-last entry of $(MAKEFILE_LIST)

Tags: makefile

I want to have 'modules' in my build system, folders that are compiled conditionally.

They would just contain a `Makefile.include` files which in the most basic case should only contain

```
include $(BASEDIR)/Makefile.module
```

`Makefile.module` would then add the `include/` directory of the modules to the include path as well as add the directory to `VPATH` and if not specified differently, would add all *.c files in the folder as *.o targets.

Now in order to do this I need to get the path of the `Makefile.module` in `Makefile.module` that included `Makefile.module`.

How would I do that? I know I can get the path of the current Makefile by retrieving the last element from `$(MAKEFILE_LIST)` with `lastword` - but how would I get the second-last element?

Comment: Not the same question exactly but the question there required the answer to this question first.